# Construct a CFG grammar that generates this language

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar, formal-grammar

this is a homework problem. The problem is:

Find a CFG that generates this language:

$ L = \{a^i b^j c^{i+j} \mid |i-j| \bmod 2 = 0\,\land\, i,j > 0\}$

Right now I have

$S  \to S_1 | S_2$

$S_1 \to aS_1b | ab$ (on each 'a', one 'b')

$S_2 \to aaaS_1b | aaab$ (on each 'aaa' one 'b')

$S_3 \to bbbS_1a | bbba$ (on each 'bbb' one 'a')

I think thats the way to get success with $|i-j| \bmod 2 = 0$, since we need to have $i + j$ = PAIR.

Could you guys, tell me if i'm wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, $S_3$ is unreachable. But even if you include it, its production rule messes up with the order of $a$'s and $b$'s.

Second, once the production has reached $S_1$, it can't escape $S_1$, so this would allow only strings where $i=j$. Also, the production rule from $S_2$ can be used only once because it sends you directly back to $S_1$. And the same happens with $S_3.$ These rules are more restrictive than the property that you want $(|i-j|\bmod 2 = 0)$. For example, they don't generate the string $a^6b^2$.

Of course, it still remains to take into account character $c$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think I'm understanding how it works. Could you give me a clue to get the c?

I do not know how to define the restriction | i-j | mod2 = 0, since as you explain in my proposal I define that i = j, but it is not the objective that I should reach.

Comment: I suggest that you fix the issues one by one. First, how would you correct the rule from $S_3$, to respect the correct order of $a$'s and $b$'s ($a$'s on the left and $b$'s on the right)?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I suggest to fix this issue with:


S -> S1 | S2

S1 -> a S1 a (i > 0)

S2 -> b S2 b (b > 0)

But I think I should add a rule to allow that the number of a's and b's are not necessarily the same, and the result of the sum is even. I do not know how I can get this the truth, I think I'm a bit lost.

Comment: I'm talking about the rule $S_3 \to bbbS_1a | bbba$. If you use this rule, it puts some $b$'s before an $a$ and this should not be allowed, because the strings should be of the form $a^ib^j(c\ldots)$. So how would you change this rule?

Comment: I guess it should be S3→aS1bbb|abbb (on each 'a' , 'bbb')

Comment: Yes, that fixes the issue. Now, you have three rules: one to make same amount of $a$'s and $b$'s, another to make two more $a$'s than $b$'s and a third rule to make two more $b$'s than $a$'s. Right? So, does it matter which of the three rules you take at every production step? In other words, if at every production step you could choose any of the three rules, would you always get $|i-j|\bmod 2 = 0$?

Comment: Thank you, so now i have the following rules:
S→S1|S2

S1→aS1b|ab

(on each 'a', one 'b')

S2→aaaS1b|aaab

(on each 'aaa' one 'b')

S3→aS1bbb|abbb (on each 'a' , 'bbb')

Asking your question, i don't think so, because we don't have the rule that allows only accept  | i − j | mod2 = 0. I mean i + j  should give an pair result. But I do not know how to assign this rule, perhaps limiting the number of b's allowed when we have an odd number of a's (so that it's also odd), and when the number of b's is even, limit the number of a's to par?

Comment: Start from the first rule $S\to \ldots$. For now, it can produce for example $S\to S_1\to ab$ and $S\to S_2\to aaab$. Note that in both cases you have an odd amount of $a$'s and also an odd amount of $b$'s. You can get even amount of $a$'s (and consequently, even amount of $b$'s for example with $S\to aS_1b\to aabb$). That's not a problem. Shouldn't you also be able to produce $S\to S_3\to bbba$?

Comment: Oh, i see now, so we force to have i + j = pair, on S2 and S3, right?. 

Answering to your question, we dont need to be able to produce bbba, because as you said before, strings should be a^i b^j, right?

Now we must find the way to fix c matter. Right?

Comment: Indeed, we enforce to have $i+j=$ even (*even* is the opposite of *odd*). The rule for $S_1$ also ensures it. I'm sorry, the '$bbba$' was a mistake. I mean that we should be able to produce $abbb$. You need the rule of $S_3$ for that. But for now, $S_3$ cannot be used because there is no way to reach it from $S$. How would you make it reachable? How would you incorporate it in your rules?

Comment: The problem is that without the rule for $S_3$ you cannot have strings with more $b$'s than $a$'s. But there is no such restriction in the language. We must be able to produce $abbb$. And wait, there's more things to fix before we go to $c$.

Comment: Oh, all right! I guess this one could work S2 → aaaS1b|aaab|S3, but i'm not sure. Once it reach S2, it continues to S3, so now we are allowed to produce 'abbb', that's true?

PD: Thank you for helping me with this problem, but I have to deliver my homework within 2 hours, and I think I will not get there in time to understand it to send properly.
Anyway, for the exam I'd like to understand it correctly, so I'll keep trying to understand it

Comment: You're welcome, but I wouldn't want to just solve your homework. And the truth is that the rules I've figured out for the problem including character $c$ are quite different from the rules we're playing with now...

Comment: Sorry if I explained wrong, I just wanted to comment that I had to deliver yesterday, so I'm not in such a hurry to get the solution, but I do want to understand how to get to a CFG from a language. Sorry if my message gave that wrong idea.

So, do you think S2 → aaaS1b|aaab|S3 will work? 

About c issue i must reefer to S2 and S3, to count the number of i and j? 

Thank you again for your time!